# Display a model field while editing others model fields

Tags: django, django-forms

What is the most straightforward way to edit some fields from a batch of objects using a formset (see below), while displaying along other fields from these models objects?

For example:

I want to display the title of a set of 10 Book objects and a form for each one in which it is possible to edit their ISBN and description.

```
class BookForm(ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Book
        fields = ('ISBN', 'description')   # The Book model has many more fields

BookFormSet = modelformset_factory(Book, form=BookForm)
```

Comment: You could read through http://stackoverflow.com/faq and, hmm, get an extra brozon badget =)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to [the doc](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/forms/modelforms/): a model form instance bound to a model object will contain a `self.instance` attribute that gives model form methods access to that specific model instance. Thus when you have a formset of Model such as `BookFormSet`

```
BookFormSet = modelformset_factory(Book, form=BookForm)
formset = BookFormSet(request.POST, queryset=Book.objects.order_by('-pk')[:10])
```

You could iterate it in template like:

```
<ul>{% for f in formset %}
    <li>{% if f.instance.pk %}title: {{ f.instance.title }}{% endif %} {{ f }}</li>
{% endfor %}</ul>
```